# Models with multiple belong_to and naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm creating my own little task system in Ruby on Rails, but I need some guidance on what to call my attributes, and if I'm thinking about the right solution.

So I have a Task model.

A task can have two relations to a user: The creator and the user that's responsible for the task.

I can of course just call my attributes: *creator:integer*, and a *responsible:integer*, but what is the preferred Ruby on Rails way of doing this?

Should they just be called the above, or *creator_user_id:integer* or should I make a relation table with a *user_id* and a *task_id* and then a role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your migration you'll want the following:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.references :creator
      t.references :responsible

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :tasks, :creator_id
    add_index :tasks, :responsible_id
  end
end
```

This was generated by: `rails g model task creator:references responsible:references`

In your database this will create a `tasks` table with two columns: `creator_id` and `responsible_id`. By default Ruby on Rails will think that these columns refer to two ActiveRecord models, `Creator` and `Responsible`. However, as you want these to refer to your `User` model you'll need to add the following to your `Task` model:

In `app/models/tasks.rb`

```
class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :responsible, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

This will tell Ruby on Rails to use the `User` model for these relations. So when you do something like `task.creator` you'll get back a `User` model, and the same for `task.responsible`.

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for mentioning the console version. I though I had to edit the migration to add the index and the reference bit. :)